# ImageMagick NOT TO CONVERT PNG bit depth

Tags: image, imagemagick, png

I have following batch script for adding transparent color to images, it is working nicely for that

```
for /f %%f in ('dir /b .') do convert %%f -transparent white tra/%%f
```

However it automatically converts bit-depth of image to 8 bpp or less if applicable. And I don't want that. Tried "-depth 32" and "-define png:bit-depth=value=32" but no luck, imagemagick still converts image to lower bit depth. 
Any help please?

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you would not want that?

Comment: @dlemstra Perhaps to simplify processing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "bit depth" in PNG refers to the bits per sample, not bits per pixel.  So "-depth 32" would mean 96-bit RGB or 128-bit RGBA, but you'd have to write to an image format that supports such large depth (not PNG, which supports only up to 16 bits/sample).

You can use

```
convert input_file -transparent white png32:output.png
```

to get 32-bit RGBA pixels (8 bits per sample), if that's what you need.

Comment: what does -transparent white do?